# boot very slowly after upgrade ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

from dmesg log, it seems that XFS loading takes much time. but I do not know where is the problem and how to fix it.

```
[    1.595606] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=334a
[    1.595607] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.595608] usb 1-12: Product: HP Business Slim Keyboard
[    1.595609] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Chicony
[    1.639808] nvidia 0000:65:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0143)
[    1.639870] nvidia 0000:65:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    1.739597] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  410.79  Thu Nov 15 10:41:04 CST 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[    1.760998] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.761668] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  410.79  Thu Nov 15 10:39:32 CST 2018
[    1.762317] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00001700] Loading driver
[    1.762319] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:17:00.0 on minor 0
[    1.762396] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00006500] Loading driver
[    1.762397] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:65:00.0 on minor 1
[    1.772657] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.772738] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.772806] scsi host2: ahci
[    1.772869] scsi host3: ahci
[    1.773630] scsi host4: ahci
[    1.773707] scsi host5: ahci
[    1.773771] scsi host6: ahci
[    1.773830] scsi host7: ahci
[    1.773849] ata1: DUMMY
[    1.773849] ata2: DUMMY
[    1.773852] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226200 irq 39
[    1.773856] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226280 irq 39
[    1.773861] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226300 irq 39
[    1.773865] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226380 irq 39
[    1.773866] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226400 irq 39
[    1.773868] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9e226000 port 0x9e226480 irq 39
[    1.774063] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SPD Write Disable is set
[    1.774106] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    1.776114] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.776114] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.777066] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.778169] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input2
[    1.778249] input: Chicony HP Business Slim Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:03F0:334A.0004/input/input3
[    1.788126] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3599.999 MHz
[    1.788133] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x33e4525366a, max_idle_ns: 440795257657 ns
[    1.836302] hid-generic 0003:03F0:334A.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Chicony HP Business Slim Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input0
[    1.836592] input: Chicony HP Business Slim Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.1/0003:03F0:334A.0005/input/input4
[    1.852367] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.896249] hid-generic 0003:03F0:334A.0005: input,hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Chicony HP Business Slim Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input1
[    1.917322] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 0c:c4:7a:e7:cd:b7
[    1.917324] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.917425] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: 0100FF-0FF
[    1.918020] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 rename3: renamed from eth0
[    2.086668] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.086783] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.087535] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.087559] ata3.00: ATA-10: CT500MX500SSD1, M3CR010, max UDMA/133
[    2.087560] ata3.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.087885] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.087963] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.088156] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.088665] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.088892] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      CT500MX500SSD1   010  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.089103] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.089119] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    2.089120] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.089124] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.089125] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.089131] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.089366]  sda: sda1
[    2.089746] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[    2.089747] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.090808] ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.091866] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.094081] ata8.00: ATAPI: ATAPI   iHAS324   F, CL8N, max UDMA/133
[    2.094977] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.231563] ata4.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MG04ACA400E, FP3B, max UDMA/100
[    2.231564] ata4.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.232837] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.233159] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MG04ACA4 FP3B PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.233368] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[    2.233369] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.233375] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    2.233376] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.233384] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.233389] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    2.238240] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ATAPI    iHAS324   F      CL8N PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.309568] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.309569] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.309699] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.309769] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[    2.476687]  sdb: sdb1
[    2.476946] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.614163] random: fast init done
[    2.812310] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.909946] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4055.0006/input/input5
[    2.910022] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    2.910047] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    2.910061] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    2.910094] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4055.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5:1
[   92.285063] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[   92.286703] XFS (sda1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[   92.299585] XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
[   92.385512] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   92.392141] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   92.412734] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   92.415357] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <so3>.
[   92.483938] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   92.484019] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   92.484114] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   92.484153] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   92.484288] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   92.484314] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   92.484353] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   92.498239] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   92.510111] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   92.540172] systemd-journald[311]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   92.634326] Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:2097148k SSFS
[   92.640386] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 236
[   92.640445] dca service started, version 1.12.1
[   92.643402] ioatdma: Intel(R) QuickData Technology Driver 4.00
[   92.684016] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.717857] idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[   92.740020] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.740306] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[   92.744333] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.842132] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[   92.842133] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[   92.842134] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[   92.842134] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-16 Joules
[   92.844806] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   92.855172] snd_hda_intel 0000:17:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   92.855192] snd_hda_intel 0000:17:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   92.865199] snd_hda_intel 0000:65:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   92.865234] snd_hda_intel 0000:65:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   92.878666] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1220: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   92.878668] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   92.878669] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   92.878670] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   92.878671] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[   92.878671] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   92.878672] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[   92.878673] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   92.878674] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[   92.889995] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input6
[   92.890037] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input7
[   92.890074] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8
[   92.890110] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
[   92.890145] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[   92.890181] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[   92.890217] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[   92.937118] random: crng init done
[   92.937119] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   93.023399] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   93.023400] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   93.155686] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000c4000-0x000c7fff window]
[   93.155820] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.7+0xda/0x120 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[   93.156719] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[   93.157204] EDAC MC1: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#1: DEV 0000:64:0c.0 (INTERRUPT)
[   93.158757] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   93.158760] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   93.158761] intel_rapl: DRAM domain energy unit 15300pj
[   93.339909] XFS (sdb1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[   93.459949] XFS (sdb1): Ending clean mount
```

**Postscript 1**

I found the 90s delay seems to be happening at random step. following is another dmesg log after reboot.

```
[    2.129405] ata3.00: ATA-10: CT500MX500SSD1, M3CR010, max UDMA/133
[    2.129408] ata3.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.130038] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.130560] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.130873] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      CT500MX500SSD1   010  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.131069] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.131097] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    2.131098] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.131102] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.131103] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.131109] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.131355]  sda: sda1
[    2.131703] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[    2.131704] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.131879] ata8.00: ATAPI: ATAPI   iHAS324   F, CL8N, max UDMA/133
[    2.132767] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.270514] ata4.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MG04ACA400E, FP3B, max UDMA/100
[    2.270517] ata4.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.271786] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.272080] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MG04ACA4 FP3B PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.272292] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[    2.272293] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.272298] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    2.272299] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.272306] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.272307] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    2.276699] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ATAPI    iHAS324   F      CL8N PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.341578] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.341580] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.341813] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.341882] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[    2.515745]  sdb: sdb1
[    2.516041] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.622700] random: fast init done
[    2.812315] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   92.283820] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   92.283827] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   92.284013] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   92.312310] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[   92.313724] XFS (sda1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[   92.327122] XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
[   92.412761] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   92.419405] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   92.436552] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   92.439092] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <so3>.
[   92.525609] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   92.525669] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   92.525771] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   92.525851] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   92.525856] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   92.525883] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   92.525926] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   92.543157] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   92.545006] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   92.607847] systemd-journald[318]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   92.641108] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 236
[   92.673815] dca service started, version 1.12.1
[   92.674554] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   92.677204] ioatdma: Intel(R) QuickData Technology Driver 4.00
[   92.679547] Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:2097148k SSFS
[   92.696021] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.869945] idma64 idma64.0: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[   92.896030] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.896295] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[   92.918134] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   92.928247] snd_hda_intel 0000:17:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   92.928268] snd_hda_intel 0000:17:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   92.928379] snd_hda_intel 0000:65:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   92.928393] snd_hda_intel 0000:65:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
```

Comment: I have tried that one, but it does not help.

Comment: You should include the output of `systemd analyse-blame`. that will more that the dmesg one.

Comment: 90 second boot delay pointed me here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1685794 , could you please verify in your fstab that the swap file/partition is existing?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much of your problem, this could be some bugs in ubuntu startup.
You could try:

1. Add some entropy

   Install `haveged` package and see if this change anything during the boot. This package provide better entropy (random things) to the kernel during boot. You could even try this without installing the package but by just moving your mouse during the boot.
2. Disable video output

   You could add `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/defautl/grub`
   Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to see if it changes something.
   This just explicitly disable the composite output; You could even try with VGA or HDMI if you don't use them, one never know

Comment: I have tried install rng-tools, haveged, add video=SVIDEO-1:d to grub, but none of them works. I just tried update my motherboard BIOS and reset BIOS configure as the last hope. miraculously, it solve the problem. but I still do not know the reason.

Comment: for reference, my motherboard is SuperMicro X11SRA and I update the BIOS from 1.0 to 1.2